# HTTP Status 500 nested exception is Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am creating basic spring MVC project with hibernate 4.3.6 and I am using oracle 11g as my database. but I am constantly getting below exception

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
```

I have installed ojdbc6 jar in my local and add it as maven dependency as well as I tried by adding as external jar but it seems its not working.please let me where I am wrong?

Here's my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>springMVC</groupId>
    <artifactId>assignment</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>assignment Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
            <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>F:\ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>assignment</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my config.java

```
package assignment.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import assignment.service.UserEntity;

@Component
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactorty=null;
public  static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    if(sessionFactorty==null){
        System.out.println("inside hibernate Util");
    Configuration configuration=new Configuration();
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(UserEntity.class);

    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "SYSTEM");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "sa");
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1158:myDb");
    SchemaExport schemaExport=new SchemaExport(configuration);
    schemaExport.create(true, true);
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder srb=new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    srb.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry=srb.build();
    sessionFactorty=configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    }
    return sessionFactorty;


}
public static void shutDown(){
    if(sessionFactorty==null)
    sessionFactorty.close();
}
}
```

Edit 1:
below SS of project structure[image]

Edit 2:
LoginController.java

```
package assignment.view;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import assignment.model.User;
import assignment.model.Validator;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    @Autowired
    Validator validator;
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String userLogin(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user){
    System.out.println(user);
    validator.process(user);
    return "success";
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Model model){
    User user=new User();
    model.addAttribute("userForm", user);
    return "Register";
}
}
```

UserEntity.java

```
package assignment.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6620152467355557520L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer userId;
@Column(nullable=false)
private String userName;
@Column(nullable=false)
private String email;
@Column(nullable=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dob;
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public Date getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(Date dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}



}
```

My Service class

```
package assignment.service;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import assignment.model.User;
import assignment.util.HibernateUtil;
import assignment.util.ServiceUtil;

@Component
public class UserService {


    public void saveUser(User user) {
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    UserEntity userEntity=new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setDob(ServiceUtil.stringToDateConverter(user.getDob()));
    userEntity.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    userEntity.setUserName(user.getUserName());
    session.save(userEntity);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.disconnect();
    HibernateUtil.shutDown();
    }

}
```

My webIntilizer (web.xml's java version)

```
package assignment.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebInitilizer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class<?>[]{WebConifg.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*edit to provide an alternative*)

A better approach than the below is to install the `ojdbc6.jar` in your Maven repo.

Supposing your are in the lib where `ojdbc6.jar` is and supposing `mvn` is installed in command line run (replace version with your version):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.3 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

After this completes successfully you can refer to it in your pom.xml with the new Maven coordinates:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
     <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
     <version>11.2.0.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

---

The error message essentially says that your Oracle jdbc driver hasn't been successfully imported into your project. I suggest creating a `lib` directory into your project directly, put the `ojdbc6.jar` in there and change the Maven coordinates for the driver to:

```
    <!-- ORACLE database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: :it didn't work have made lib folder and updated my question with my project structure please verify.

Comment: That is correct, now the ojdbc jar should be visible by maven and added in the classpath. Have you run 'mvn clean package' ?. are you getting the same error?

Comment: yes and yes getting same error.I did maven build with clean install goal. but it is not coming in my class path

Comment: can you please post all needed classes/files to be easier reproducible so we get the full picture

Comment: Have added most of the files please let me know if anything else required

Comment: HEy I got warning something like this  **'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib/ojdbc6.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 34, column 16**

Comment: I've provided an alternative of how to get the jar first installed in your Maven repo and retrieve it from there

Comment: can you please tell me how to do using eclipse??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130329/discussion-between-vihang-shah-and-dimitrisli).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting your ojdbc6.jar in [JAVA_HOME]/jre/lib/ext